# How to update dynamically in autocomplete textview using json in android

Tags: json, android-studio, autocompletetextview

I'm beginner in `Android` Application, I wanted to list the categories in the `autocompletetextview` from the webservices (`JSON` format). There some set of categories in web services and I need to list them in the dropdown box and the webservices is written in `JSON` format. Kindly help me out to solve this. Provide me solution for this.

Comment: show what you tried..and also your json response..with details

Comment: You can implement `Filterable` and update dynamically. Check out this link https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete

Comment: I think you can refer to my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047156/how-to-create-custom-baseadapter-for-autocompletetextview/33049491#33049491, hope it helps!