# how to use autocompleteTextView using WebServices in Android?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-textwatcher

I am trying to make **Autocomplete Textview** in which whenever user enter **"#" keyword** than only autocomplete textview will hit the API and show the list of choices below(just like Spinner) and user will select from the list.

for eg. Below is the Image in which Developer is the selected word from the list, similarly I have entered movies and the option is displayed in list and selected word will be highlighted just like developer word.

I am not getting , how to achieve this .Is there any library available for this or any link which can help me .

:-[image]

Comment: For getting data from web service (except highlighting), please read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047156/how-to-create-custom-baseadapter-for-autocompletetextview/33049491#33049491 to see if it can help or not